# Should this fugue subject be regarded as syncopated?

Tags: syncopation

The following fugue subject is from Muffat's *12 Toccatas and 72 Versets*...

[image]

My understanding of the broad meaning of syncopation is any rhythm that displaces the sense of regular strong beats.

Additionally, an *agogic* accent is an accented created through relatively longer notes vales.

So, in `3/4` time, an unsyncopated, regular metrical rhythm might be something like one half note and one quarter note per measure. I suppose dotted half notes in `3/4` would be the most unsyncopated and metrical rhythm.

Anyway, in the first two measures of the example fugue subject relatively short values are used on beats one and longer values on weak beats two or three. The accents of those notes being agogic.

That seems, to me, to mean that the subject's beginning features syncopation. Does that make sense to you?

I figure there are varying levels of syncopation. So something like syncopation on up strokes is very strong, tying or a duration over beats 2 and 3 in `4/4` is more moderate. This fugue subject is fairly moderate syncopation. Beyond a purely academic question, I ask because understanding such subtleties of rhythm in this way helps me understand the character of a piece. This particular fugue subject seems to have certain assertiveness. A tempo a bit on the faster side seems to fit that character.

Comment: Hm, seems to revolve around the definition of the word syncopation, and that's hard because it's not a clear-cut technical term, just a general notion. Also, does this count as hemiola? And does hemiola "count as syncopation"? Yes and yes, to me, but I'm not sure how far we get with that...

Comment: @AndyBonner Since this depends on the definition of syncopation there's no clear answer.

Comment: How syncopated is syncopated? I wouldn't give this as an example of what syncopation means. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I woudn't either except for what I wrote about in my question regarding the meaning and effect of syncopation.

Comment: @Andy Bonner Syncopation is an emphasis on the downbeat any longer notes on the weak part of the beat/pulse is syncopation. I don't know what part of it is not well-defined.

Comment: To me this question is more complicated by the word “should” than by “syncopated”. **Can** it be regarded as syncopated? Sure. **Should** it be regarded as syncopated? Seems subjective.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, if I understand the broader definition, it seems I should regard it as syncopation. My question is then posed to  others who understand rhythm theory at a higher level than me. Someone who can either confirm that or point out where I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: It seems very strange the votes to close a question about music theory on a music theory forum. This is no more subjective than doing a harmonic analysis. It's a question about _rhythm_ analysis.

Comment: Analysis absolutely can be subjective. That’s not me saying that, it’s from a phd in theory.

Comment: Right, so if subjective harmony analysis is on topic for this forum, why wouldn't subjective rhythm analysis? @ToddWilcox

Answer (score 1):

> Should this fugue subject be regarded as syncopated?

No.  It COULD be, marginally.  SHOULD is far too strong.

Comment: What about a rhythm like, in 4/4, quarter note, half, quarter? Is that not syncopation?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis  If it was 2/2, barely.   In 4/4 everything's dead on the beat.